# Amazon Polly Character Limit Increase

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

According to a recent AWS announcement, the new character limit for Polly is 3,000 -- double the previous limit of 1,500.

Previously, my application had a character limit of 1,450 to account for characters I'm adding programatically to the user's input. In view of the above announcement, I thought increasing my character limit to 2,950 would be safe. However, my audio files are empty (0 kb) anytime I surpass about 2,450 characters. I'm baffled by this and of course I would like to use the extra 500 characters if possible.

Here is my code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    fs = require('fs');
    const Fs = require('fs')
    const path = require('path');
    AWS.config.loadFromPath(path.join(__dirname, 'config.json'));
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var localfile = path.join(__dirname, 'myverse.mp3');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host     : '...',
  user     : '...',
  password : '...',
  database: '...',
});


[some irrelevant code omitted here.]

    connection.query('SELECT versetext, book, mp3, id, reference, userid FROM publicverses where mp3 = "empty" limit 1',
    function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(error);
    var scripture = results[0].versetext + ".";
    var userid = results[0].userid;
    var book = results[0].book;
    var reference = results[0].reference.replace(":", " verse ").replace(",", " and ");
    if (reference.includes("-")){
      var reference = reference.replace("verse", "verses");
    }
    console.log(scripture + " " +  book.replace("1", "first").replace("2", "second").replace("3", "third") + " " + reference);
    var myverse = "<speak><prosody volume='x-loud'><break time='1s'/>" + scripture + " " +  book.replace("1", "first").replace("2", "second").replace("3", "third") + " " + reference + "<break time='1s'/></prosody></speak>";
    var link = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/publicverses/" + book.replace(/ /g, "")+reference.replace(/ /g, "")+"_user"+userid+"_"+randomnumber+".mp3";

    writeit();
     fs.createWriteStream(localfile);
    var myvalue = fs.createReadStream(localfile);
    setTimeout(uploadit, 2000)

function linkit(){
  'use strict';
   connection.query('update publicverses set mp3 = ? where mp3 = "empty" limit 1', [link],
    function (error, results, fields) {
      console.log(error)

    })

}


function writeit() {
  'use strict';
  const Polly = new AWS.Polly({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'us-east-1'
})

let params = {
    'Text': myverse.replace(" Job ", " Jobe "),
    'LexiconNames': [ 'kjv' ],
    'TextType': 'ssml',
    'OutputFormat': 'mp3',
    'VoiceId': 'Matthew'
}

Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.code)
    } else if (data) {
        if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
            Fs.writeFile("./myverse.mp3", data.AudioStream, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                console.log("Verse recorded successfully!")
            })
        }
    }
})

}

function uploadit () {
  'use strict';
  console.log('Preparing to upload the verse.')
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
  var uploadParams = {Bucket: 'publicverses', key: '/test.mp3', Body: myvalue, ACL: 'public-read'};
  var file = 'MyVerse.mp3';

  var fs = require('fs');
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('File Error', err);
  });
  uploadParams.Body = fileStream;

  var path = require('path');
  uploadParams.Key = book.replace(/ /g, "")+reference.replace(/ /g, "")+"_user"+userid+"_"+randomnumber+".mp3";

  // call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
  s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } if (data) {
      console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
      linkit();
      addanother();
    }
  });

}

  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? I just used the `aws polly synthesize-speech` command on input text of 2800 characters and it worked fine. Try saving the text you are sending to Polly and run it through the CLI to see if you get any further information.